# Shift in datatable evaluation

Tags: r, data.table

I was trying to use `shift` in datatable as follows:

```
DT <- data.table(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), b = c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B"))
DT[!is.na(shift(a, 1)), xy := shift(a, 1), by = b]
```

This was just a test to demonstrate the issue: in the second row, `xy` is NA. The reason for that is that shift in the evaluation `i` part (as part of: `DT[i,j,by]`) does not account for the by-keyword, whereas `j` does. This seems confusing to me. Is there a reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting a `NA`-value in the second row is because you are filtering out the first row with `!is.na(shift(a,1))`, see:

```
> DT[, !is.na(shift(a, n = 1))]
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

This is not included in the `by`-operation because the filtering in `i` is done before the grouping.

As a result `xy := shift(a, 1)` will look at only the rows 2 to 7.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but why do I have to specify a `fill` value there and not in `j`?

Comment: Now you changed the solution as well. Why? The first one works as well. Please explain a bit more what you are doing. I have never seen a multiplier used in `j` before. I wonder if it is practical for bigger examples. Let's say a shift of `a` by 2 has also to be non-na, for example. So we just multiply everything?

Comment: @Talik3233 added an explanation

Comment: thanks I understood that. But now you removed your solution as well

Comment: @Talik3233 I removed it because it wasn't the correct answer imo. But you can look back at it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50412238/revisions)

Comment: Ok thanks for the link. Why not correct? Looks correct to me.

Comment: @Talik3233 because the old alternative are basically the same as `DT[, xy := shift(a, n = 1), by = b]`

Comment: Thanks, well in your current answer you state the reason for the behavior, which I also knew; but what I was looking for is an explanation or an answer or an confirmation that this cannot be intentional

Comment: @Talik3233 It is intentional. If you want to apply the filter by group first and then create the new variable you can do: `DT[, .SD[!is.na(shift(a, 1))], by = b][, xy := shift(a, n = 1), by = b][]`